# Current row and column in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Is there a command to get the number of the current row and column while you're in a matrix? I know nicematrix has iRow and jCol, but I was curious if regular matrices have any command like that, as it would help for something I'm doing.

Comment: no, https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues/34  (you could use tabularray environments as well, they have row and column count)